# Cookie issue on customer login magento - Chrome

Tags: magento-1, cookie

HI I am facing a weird issue only on Opera and Chrome. I cannot login with a customer account. This is my configuration:
[image]

I tried to change the domain like:

1. www.myurl.de
2. myurl.de
3. leave it empty

None of them are working. The form key is set in the `<form>`, in the logs file nothing. 
I commented the code

`call_user_func_array(‘session_set_cookie_params’, $cookieParams);`

from `Varien.php` 
and from `public function login($username, $password)`

`$this->renewSession();`

The Fpc is disabled. The sessions are stored in db. I don't know what else should I try ?

Comment: actually what is your issue, please add that as well. :)

Comment: i cannot login with a valid customer account, I added to the description :)

Comment: why you are setting cookies life time as 0? make it as atleast 1 hour. Please set as 3600.

Comment: and also make cookie domain empty.

Comment: I left the cookie domain empty and also I set it to 33600 :D or 9600 , Even if I set it to 9 millions it doesn't make the difference :D

Comment: and i have 2 `frontend cookies` the only differences between them is the domain. For one of them I have the extra `.`  so `.www.myurl.com` and the other is `www.myurl.com`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/52724/discussion-between-attila-naghi-and-shyam-krishna-sreekumar).